# slope and morphism of bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $L_1, L_2$ be two line bundles on a smooth projective variety $X$. Consider that there exists a non-zero homomorphism $f:L_1 \to L_2$. Over curve this gives us $\text{deg}(L_1) \leq \text{deg}(L_2)$ (Please correct me if this is wrong).

If we now consider $X$ to be a higher dimensional variety (say a surface), $H$ be an ample divisor on $X$ and a non-zero morphism  $f:E_1 \to E_2$ between two rank $r$ bundles. Then do we have the analogous result that $\text{slope}_H(E_1) \leq \text{slope}_H(E_1)$?

If this is not true in general, then what can be said about their slope realtion?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The morphism should be generically injective, otherwise this is wrong.

Comment: @Sasha, given a nonzero morphism of line bundles ( injectivity/ surjectivity not known) over surface, is there a way to relate/ compare their degree?

Comment: A nonzero morphism of line bundles is generically injective, so the answer is positive.

Comment: @Sasha, I see. Perhaps, earlier you meant that it is true for line bundles but does not generalize to higher rank vector bundles. Then Can anything be said about slopes of higher rank bundles when it is not known whether the map is generically injective or not?

Comment: No. Just imagine $E_i = E_0 \oplus E'_i$ and $f$ is $E_0 \oplus E'_1 \to E_0 \to E_0 \oplus E'_2$, the composition of the projection to $E_0$ and embedding of $E_0$.

Comment: @Sasha, I see. What if both of them are slope semistable (or stable) with respect to $H$?

Comment: For semistable sheaves there is always an inequality of slopes, no mater if the map is generically injective or not, even no matter if the ranks are the same or not.

Comment: @Sasha, by `an inequality` do you mean $\mu_H(E_1) \leq \mu_H(E_2)$? (or something else?)

Answer (score 1):

In the following proof, $\{0\}=E_{k,0}\subsetneqq E_{k,1}\subsetneqq\dotsc\subsetneqq E_{k,m_k-1}\subsetneqq E_{k,m_k}=E_k$ is the Harder-Narasimhan filtration (HN-filtration, for short) of $E_k$ and $\mu(E_{k,m_k})=\deg_H(E_{k,m_k})/\mathrm{rank}(E_{k,m_k})$, where $k\in\{1,2\}$, $H$ is a polarization of $X$, and $X$ is a smooth projective variety of dimension greater or equal than $1$.

Suppose that there exists $0\neq f\in\hom(E_1,E_2)$ and $\mu(E_{1,m_1}/E_{1,m_1-1})>\mu(E_{2,1})$. Let $i$ be the minimal index such that $f(E_{1,i})\neq0$ and let $j$ be the minimal index such that $f(E_{1,i})\subseteq E_{2,j}$. Then there is a non-trivial morphism $\widetilde{f}\colon E_{1,i}/E_{1,i-1}\to E_{2,j}/E_{2,j-1}$, but
$$
\mu(E_{1,i}/E_{1,i-1})\geq\mu(E_{1,m_1}/E_{1,m_1-1})>\mu(E_{2,1})\geq\mu(E_{2,j}/E_{2,j-1})
$$
and this is absurd because $Im\left(\widetilde{f}\right)$ is a torsion-free quotient sheaf of $E_1$ and a subsheaf of $E_2$, $\mu\left(Im\left(\widetilde{f}\right)\right)\leq\mu(E_{2,1})<\mu(E_{1,m_1}/E_{1,m_1-1})\leq\mu\left(Im\left(\widetilde{f}\right)\right)$, and these sheaves are semistable.

Thus, in general, if $\mu(E_{1,m_1}/E_{1,m_1-1})>\mu(E_{2,1})$ then $\hom(E_1,E_2)=\{0\}$. Applying this statement to (semi)stable vector bundles, in particular to line bundles, one has $\hom(E_1,E_2)\neq\{0\}\Rightarrow\mu(E_1)\leq\mu(E_2)$.